# 0x02, 0x03 hex-chars in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, char, hex

I'm currently working on a server-client project and i'm writing a little tcp iPhone app client. The problem is, that I've to send the server a "packet" with the following formae:

`0x02` + a string + `0x09` + an int + `0x03`

The problem is, that I don't know how to include the 0x02 (as hex). At the end, I should send everything as NSData.

Here is what I've got so far.

```
unsigned char tag_start = 0x02;
unsigned char tag_end = 0x03;
unsigned char tag_split = 0x09;

NSString * stringToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c%@%c%@%c%@%c%@%c", tag_start, oobject, tag_split, oid, tag_split, oaction, tag_split, ovalue, tag_end];

NSData * dataToSend = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[stringToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Wrong is, that the, STX 0x02 will change to NSString 0x32

Comment: To convert an NSInteger (or an unsigned char) to a hex string, you can use the `%x` format specifier for NSString.  Something like this: `[NSString stringWithFormat@"0x%x", tag_start"]` would produce 0x2 (which is the same value as 0x02).

Comment: Thank's for this tipp, but it doesn't work. The chars in the result aren't  STX, ETX, CSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way:

```
NSString *_command = @"\x02...\x09...\x03";
```

it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I used, in a similar problem, the NSMutableData and worked then with `appendBytes` (to append STX, ETX, CSM) or `appendData` (NSString).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this already, but got problems to add the STX,... How have you managed to add them?

Answer (score 0):

Heres how it works:

```
NSMutableData * mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// Appends STX
[mutableData appendData: [NSData dataWithBytes: "\x02" length:1]];

// Appends ETX
[mutableData appendData: [NSData dataWithBytes: "\x09" length:1]];

// Appends CSM
[mutableData appendData: [NSData dataWithBytes: "\x03" length:1]];
```

My problem was that the server didn't respond to my messages, but the messages were correct.